# Tools/addons to edit how pages are rendered in browser

Tags: browser-addons, firefox-extensions, adblock

I'm looking for something what seems to be quite straightforward but I am not successful so I clearly take a wrong approach. I would like to have more power over displaying pages than usual ad-blocking add-ons offer, like 'do not display first table element on this domain', or 'do not display second column in the body on this site'. I tried tinker with custom filters in ublock in Firefox but honestly, I couldn't figure out how those filters work, though I am familiar with basic HTML/CSS. What exactly am I looking for? :-)

Comment: You need [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/es/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) for Firefox. It lets you tinker with specific portions of specific webpages

Comment: Seems this Greasemonkey evolved into something names Stylish and other forks, still reading wiki regarding that. Generally it is called 'userscripts', thanks a lot for pointing in the right direction.